# Inits and Tails Function

Tags: haskell

Hey guys i need to declare the inits and tails function for my assigment

so far i got

```
inits [] = [[]]
inits (x:xs) =  [x]: inits (xs)
```

this gives me for an input inits [1,2] the output [[1,2],[1],[],[]]
well this looks more like a failure version of the inits tails function which output should be [[1,2],[1],[]]

The output for the inits should be for the input [[],[1],[1,2]]

I don't expect someone to give me the solution, i just could need some tips how i should change my code, i am new into haskell

Comment: Take a concrete example. `inits [1,2,3] == [[1], [1,2], [1,2,3]]`, so "factor out" the 1 to notice that `1` needs to be added to *each* element of `[[], [2], [2,3]]`.

Comment: (Er, `inits [1,2,3]` should be `[[], [1], [1,2], [1,2,3]]`, but the same logic applies.)

Comment: How does the same logic apply? You can't factor out a `1` of the empty list.

Comment: @cafce It's not the *entire* answer, but it's part of the answer.

Comment: "This gives me for an input inits [1,2] the output [[1,2],[1],[],[]]" -- no, it doesn't. (And the difference between the actual output and the output you thought it had actually contains a clue about what's gone wrong.)

Answer (score 2):

Compare two concrete examples:

```
> inits [1,2,3]
[[],[1],[1,2],[1,2,3]]
> inits [2,3]
[[],[2],[2,3]]
```

What steps do you need to take to turn the second result into the first one?

Comment: I need to add the first index into a single elemented list and after that step i should append with my next list where i have +1 element which is the index i+1, so it would be like [[],[1],[1,2],[1,2,3]]

Answer (score 1):

On my way to write the code of the inits function the code of the tails function came out:

```
tails :: [Int] -> [[Int]]
tails [] = [[]]
tails (x:xs) =  (x:xs): tails xs
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to explicit recursion, an approach to writing `tails` would be to use `scanr`, which works much like `foldr` but saves the intermediate results as a list.

```
Prelude> scanr (:) [] [1,2,3]
[[1,2,3],[2,3],[3],[]]
Prelude> scanr (:) [] $ tail [1,2,3]
[[2,3],[3],[]]
Prelude> tails = scanr (:) [] . tail
Prelude> tails [1,2,3]
[[2,3],[3],[]]
```

Implementing `inits` can similarly be achieved using `scanl`:

```
Prelude> scanl (flip (:)) [] [1,2,3]
[[],[1],[2,1],[3,2,1]]
Prelude> map reverse $ scanl (flip (:)) [] [1,2,3]
[[],[1],[1,2],[1,2,3]]
Prelude> inits = map reverse . scanl (flip (:)) []
Prelude> inits [1,2,3]
[[],[1],[1,2],[1,2,3]]
```